# How to remove Extended WPF Toolkit from my project?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, wpf-extended-toolkit

I downloaded and added into references Extended WPF Toolkit (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/96972), but ended up not using it. Now I want to remove it from my solution, but don't know how. I tried deleteng the packages folder, but it gets downloaded automatically when compiling the project. Also tried finding it among references, but I just couldn't find it. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. How can I permanently remove the toolkit?

Comment: "it gets downloaded automatically when compiling" - do you mean toolkit libraries still exists in bin directory after you compiling solution? Did you tried to *clear* solution (through right click on solution name in solution explorer) or delete bin folder *manually*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on `project ->Manage Nuget packages ->Installed packages`
click on `Extended.Wpf.Toolkit` from the `list->Uninstall`

Comment: @Tomáš Zajda Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong.  You have installed it via `Nuget` packages that will automatically restore the missing packages.  Give a try on this.

Go to the `TOOLS -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` and enter the following:

`Uninstall-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit`